# popped a warning message to before adding the data into excel sheet from user form

Tags: vba, excel

this is my code. I want to check if the data exist in the excel worksheet before adding. And if it does exist, popped a msgbox to continue adding the data .

- 1)Press the add button
- 2) check if the data exist 3) if exist, shoW msg "existing data.Are you sure to add the record"
- 3.1) If user click yes, enter the record
- 3.2) if click no, then clear data in the textbox and allow user to refilL
- 4.If data not exist, enter to the last row

CAN ANYONE HELP SPOT AND CORRECT MY MISTAKE IN THE CODE?

```
Private Sub Addbutton_Click()

Sheets("MASTER").Activate
Dim lastrow
Dim answer As String
Dim newRecordRow As Integer
Dim isFound As Boolean
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow = lastrow + 1
newRecordRow = 1


If Me.Entity.Text = Empty Then 'Entity
MsgBox "Please enter the entity.", vbExclamation
Me.Entity.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
Exit Sub 'terminate here


 End If

If Me.Branch.Text = Empty Then 'Branch
MsgBox "Please enter the Branch.", vbExclamation
Me.Branch.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
Exit Sub 'terminate here
End If

If Me.Emailname.Text = Empty Then 'Emailname
MsgBox "Please enter the email name.", vbExclamation
Me.Emailname.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
Exit Sub 'terminate here
End If

If Me.Attention.Text = Empty Then 'Attention
MsgBox "Enter the attention names.", vbExclamation
Me.Attention.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
Exit Sub 'terminate here
End If

If Me.emailcc.Text = Empty Then 'Emailcc
MsgBox "Enter the cc names.", vbExclamation
Me.emailcc.SetFocus 'position cursor to try again
Exit Sub 'terminate here
End If

Do While (IsEmpty(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(newRecordRow, 3).Value) = False And isFound = False)


If (UCase(Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(newRecordRow, 3).Value) = UCase(Branch)) Then
Branch.Text = (Branch)
isFound = True
End If
Loop
If isFound = True Then
answer = MsgBox("Existing data.Are you sure to add the record", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
Else
newRecordRow = newRecordRow + 1
Cells(lastrow, 2) = Entity.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = Branch.Text
Cells(lastrow, 4) = Product.Value
Cells(lastrow, 5) = Emailname.Value
Cells(lastrow, 6) = Attention.Value
Cells(lastrow, 7) = Emailadd.Value
Cells(lastrow, 8) = emailcc.Value
Cells(lastrow, 9) = ccadd.Value

If answer = vbYes Then
Cells(lastrow, 2) = Entity.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = Branch.Text
Cells(lastrow, 4) = Product.Value
Cells(lastrow, 5) = Emailname.Value
Cells(lastrow, 6) = Attention.Value
Cells(lastrow, 7) = Emailadd.Value
Cells(lastrow, 8) = emailcc.Value
Cells(lastrow, 9) = ccadd.Value
Unload Me
Else

answer = MsgBox("Do you want to add a new record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")

'Clear data first
With Me
.Entity.Text = ""
.Branch.Text = ""
.Product.Text = ""
.Emailname.Text = ""
.Attention.Text = ""
.Emailadd.Text = ""
.emailcc.Text = ""
.ccadd.Text = ""
End With

Entity.Value = Cells(lastrow, 2)
Branch.Value = Cells(lastrow, 3)
Product.Value = Cells(lastrow, 4)
Emailname.Value = Cells(lastrow, 5)
Attention.Value = Cells(lastrow, 6)
Emailadd.Value = Cells(lastrow, 7)
emailcc.Value = Cells(lastrow, 8)
ccadd.Value = Cells(lastrow, 9)



End If
End If


Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens? Where does it stop doing what you expect it to?

Comment: It may help to properly indent your code so you can follow the logic correctly

Comment: the msgbox does not appear properly and even if i add non-exist data the msg box of existing data found still appear

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I don't have time to go through all of it but it is properly indented now and you should be able to follow it a lot easier and maybe debug it yourself.

I also qualified your instances of `Cells` with a worksheet the correct way (`ws`). Hopefully that will fix the problem. I may have messed up the logic at the end - the code kind of gets convoluted and unclear..

---

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Addbutton_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
Dim lastrow As Long, answer As String, newRecordRow As Integer, isFound As Boolean

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
newRecordRow = 1


If Me.Entity.Text = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the entity.", vbExclamation
    Me.Entity.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.Branch.Text = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the Branch.", vbExclamation
    Me.Branch.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.Emailname.Text = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the email name.", vbExclamation
    Me.Emailname.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.Attention.Text = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Enter the attention names.", vbExclamation
    Me.Attention.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.emailcc.Text = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Enter the cc names.", vbExclamation
    Me.emailcc.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If


Do While (IsEmpty(.ws.Cells(newRecordRow, 3).Value) = False And isFound = False)
    If (UCase(ws.Cells(newRecordRow, 3).Value) = UCase(Branch)) Then
        Branch.Text = (Branch)
        isFound = True
    End If
Loop


If Not isFound Then 'Double Negative (This means isFound is False)
    newRecordRow = newRecordRow + 1
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 2) = Entity.Text
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 3) = Branch.Text
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 4) = Product.Value
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 5) = Emailname.Value
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 6) = Attention.Value
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 7) = Emailadd.Value
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 8) = emailcc.Value
    ws.Cells(lastrow, 9) = ccadd.Value
Else 'If isFound is True
    answer = MsgBox("Existing data.Are you sure to add the record", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 2) = Entity.Text
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 3) = Branch.Text
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 4) = Product.Value
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 5) = Emailname.Value
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 6) = Attention.Value
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 7) = Emailadd.Value
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 8) = emailcc.Value
            ws.Cells(lastrow, 9) = ccadd.Value
        End If
End If

answer = MsgBox("Do you want to add a new record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")

If answer = vbYes Then
    With Me
        .Entity.Text = ""
        .Branch.Text = ""
        .Product.Text = ""
        .Emailname.Text = ""
        .Attention.Text = ""
        .Emailadd.Text = ""
        .emailcc.Text = ""
        .ccadd.Text = ""
    End With

    Entity.Value = ws.ws.Cells(lastrow, 2)
    Branch.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 3)
    Product.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 4)
    Emailname.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 5)
    Attention.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 6)
    Emailadd.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 7)
    emailcc.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 8)
    ccadd.Value = ws.Cells(lastrow, 9)
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```